# intel xdk alert not showing title and ok button on built app but displays on emulator

Tags: intel-xdk

hi i have this jquery code that should display an alert box if jquery post parameter is successful which i am using on my intel xdk app.

my biggest problem is that it displays correctly on intel xdk emulator but when i build the app using cordova build and install it on my android phone the alert shows a white screen as shown below.

Please help

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0X41E.png)

here is my code

$("#codeSubmit").live('click',function() {

```
var data = $("#codeVerification :input").serializeArray();

$.post($("#codeVerification").attr('action'), data, function(json){

    if (json.page == "mainpage") {

        intel.xdk.notification.alert(json.message,'Alert','Ok');
    }
    if (json.status == "brand") {

        $('#mainpage').hide();

        $('#brands').show();

    }
}, "json");
```

});

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At this point, I think all the `intel.xdk.whatever` libraries are deprecated. Intel has been saying to move to the cordova plugins when possible for several months. You will want to use cordova-plugin-dialogs, which you can include in your project via the Plugin Management section of the project settings page (where you set up the build info). It is called "Notifications" when you look in the list under Core Plugins

[image: Plugin Dialog]

Comment: apparently the solution seems not to work.  updated code.$("#codeSubmit").live('click',function() {
    
$('#spinner').css('visibility', 'visible');

var data = $("#codeVerification :input").serializeArray();

$.post($("#codeVerification").attr('action'), data, function(json){

    if (json.page == "mainpage") {

        navigator.notification.alert(json.message,display('mainpage'));
    }
    if (json.status == "brand") {

        $('#mainpage').hide();

        $('#brand').show();

    }
}, "json");

});

Comment: @shev - I will be able to look at this again much later today. It would be easier to read your code if you added it into your question in code format. One thing I do see however is that you are not passing a function as the second parameter (the callback). At a minimum `display('mainpage')` should be `function(){display('mainpage');}`